# Working With Linq Query in Mapping

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a class containing three Methods which are working perfectly :

1. To fetch the data from table :

   ```
       public IList<RetriveOperatorAcYo> GetRetriveOperatorListGrid(int Uid)
       {
           var persons = (from p in _Context.People
                         join a in _Context.Accounts on p.PersonId equals a.PersonId
                         join b in _Context.BusinessTypes on a.BusinessTypeId equals b.BusinessTypeId
                         join d in _Context.AccountUserRelations on a.AccountId equals d.AccountId
                         where b.Name == AccountBusinessTypes.Operator && a.IsDelete == false && d.Active == true && d.UserId == Uid
                         select p);
           return MapToRetriveOperatorYoList(persons);
       }
   ```
2. Use as middle function for separating list to single element :

   ```
       private IList<RetriveOperatorAcYo> MapToRetriveOperatorYoList(IEnumerable<EntityFramework.Person> persons)
       {
           return persons.Select(MapToRetirveOperatorYo).ToList();
       }
   ```
3. As a Mapping function to generate result :

   ```
       private RetriveOperatorAcYo MapToRetirveOperatorYo(EntityFramework.Person person)
       {
           var vendorYo = new RetriveOperatorAcYo
           {
               Id = person.PersonId,
               FirstName = person.FirstName,
               LastName = person.LastName,
               MobileNumber = person.MobileNumber,
               LandlineNumber = person.LandlineNumber
           }

           return vendorYo;
      }
   ```

Now I want to fetch only particular columns data in my first function.

I searched some techniques and tried this :

```
var persons = (from p in _Context.People
               join a in _Context.Accounts on p.PersonId equals a.PersonId
               join b in _Context.BusinessTypes on a.BusinessTypeId equals b.BusinessTypeId
               join d in _Context.AccountUserRelations on a.AccountId equals d.AccountId
               where b.Name == AccountBusinessTypes.Operator && a.IsDelete == false && d.Active == true && d.UserId == Uid
               select new 
               {
                  PersonId = p.PersonId,
                  FirstName = p.FirstName,
                  LastName = p.LastName,
                  MobileNumber = p.MobileNumber,
                  LandlineNumber = p.LandlineNumber
               });
```

But it giving me the **error** in the second function :

> "The entity or complex type cannot be constructed in a LINQ to
>   Entities query."

So is there any solution how to map the data and return the particular mapped class with particular details only.

Thanks for the Help in Advance.

Comment: The third function doesn't return anything. Also, shouldn't the second function be something like this: `return persons.Select(p => MapToRetirveOperatorYo(p)).ToList();`?

Comment: Sorry i forget to add that now i have added that..

Comment: How about the second function, does it work if you change the return to use the proper lambda expression?

Comment: Yes It's working Very fine with my above code but the problem is with the query that i want to change for the mapping of necessary columns from tables

Comment: Is RetriveOperatorAcYo an entity or a plain DTO?

Comment: It's a Plain class containing the objects same as Table having for mapping.

Comment: Does the error message that you got specify which type cannot be constructed?

Comment: No..it returns the object name (i.e. Tablename) of entity model..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To maintain the pattern with the 3 methods and do the partial query you want, while not using your existing DTO in the first method, you will have to resort to passing around dynamic objects and change your method signatures.  Something like this should work, although it's not recommended - note the use of `dynamic` in the 2nd and 3rd methods:

```
public IList<RetriveOperatorAcYo> GetRetriveOperatorListGrid(int Uid)
{
    var persons = (from p in _Context.People
        join a in _Context.Accounts on p.PersonId equals a.PersonId
        join b in _Context.BusinessTypes on a.BusinessTypeId equals b.BusinessTypeId
        join d in _Context.AccountUserRelations on a.AccountId equals d.AccountId
        where b.Name == AccountBusinessTypes.Operator && a.IsDelete == false && d.Active == true && d.UserId == Uid
        select new 
        {
            PersonId = p.PersonId,
            FirstName = p.FirstName,
            LastName = p.LastName,
            MobileNumber = p.MobileNumber,
            LandlineNumber = p.LandlineNumber
         });
    return MapToRetirveOperatorYo(persons);
}

private IList<RetriveOperatorAcYo> MapToRetriveOperatorYoList(IEnumerable<dynamic> persons)
{
    return persons.Select(MapToRetirveOperatorYo).ToList();
}

private RetriveOperatorAcYo MapToRetirveOperatorYo(dynamic person)
{
    var vendorYo = new RetriveOperatorAcYo
    {
        Id = person.PersonId,
        FirstName = person.FirstName,
        LastName = person.LastName,
        MobileNumber = person.MobileNumber,
        LandlineNumber = person.LandlineNumber
    }
    return vendorYo;
```

}

The better option would be to change your first method to `select new RetriveOperatorAcYo`, as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23755972/2278086).

Answer (score 2):

You have not specified which class should be created with the LINQ query.
Try

```
var persons = (from p in _Context.People
           join a in _Context.Accounts on p.PersonId equals a.PersonId
           join b in _Context.BusinessTypes on a.BusinessTypeId equals b.BusinessTypeId
           join d in _Context.AccountUserRelations on a.AccountId equals d.AccountId
           where b.Name == AccountBusinessTypes.Operator && a.IsDelete == false && d.Active == true && d.UserId == Uid
           select new RetriveOperatorAcYo()
           {
              PersonId = p.PersonId,
              FirstName = p.FirstName,
              LastName = p.LastName,
              MobileNumber = p.MobileNumber,
              LandlineNumber = p.LandlineNumber
           });
```

Comment: Yeah this is also the option but I don't want to create new class with name "RetriveOperatorAcYo()". I want to use this in my next function directly so what I can do for that?

Comment: Are you looking for something like an anonymous class? Jon Skeet found a possibility to do it here: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/01/09/horrible-grotty-hack-returning-an-anonymous-type-instance.aspx . It allows to return anonymous instances, even if it's not something you would want to do.

Comment: No I want to use the query for the Next function that i have described in No.2 so that it will take the data and map to No.3

Comment: Why don't you use Person as the select type then?

Comment: We have also tried that but it gives the error of mapping to objects rather then using of entity model table.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370028/return-list-using-select-new-in-linq Method can not return anonymous type it has to be same as the type defined in method return type.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54030/discussion-between-x-developer-and-user1648371).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this approach is that the EF cannot partially load an EF type with selected columns. If you load a type with partial information it doesn't know how to handle the rest of the columns that remain unfilled. What should it do in an update? In order to use these partial columns you can create another class to hold this information for you. But even then you have to decide what to do with the unselected columns in your `MapToRetirveOperatorYo` method. Here is to demonstrate:

```
public class PersonDTO
        {
            public long PersonID { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
            public string LandlineNumber { get; set; }
        }
```

Now you can use this class when you want to create your anonymous class:

```
var persons = (from p in _Context.People
                join a in _Context.Accounts on p.PersonId equals a.PersonId
                join b in _Context.BusinessTypes on a.BusinessTypeId equals b.BusinessTypeId
                join d in _Context.AccountUserRelations on a.AccountId equals d.AccountId
                where b.Name == AccountBusinessTypes.Operator && a.IsDelete == false && d.Active == true && d.UserId == Uid
                select new PersonDTO()
                {
                    PersonId = p.PersonId,
                    FirstName = p.FirstName,
                    LastName = p.LastName,
                    MobileNumber = p.MobileNumber,
                    LandlineNumber = p.LandlineNumber
                });
```

In your other function:

```
private IList<RetriveOperatorAcYo> MapToRetriveOperatorYoList(IEnumerable<PersonDTO> persons)
{
        //here you have to decide what to do with Email, DOB and active as 
        //you are not selecting those in your Person DTO class ! Here is where EF would not know what to do.
        return person.Select(person => new RetriveOperatorAcYo
        {
            Id = person.PersonId,
            FirstName = person.FirstName,
            LastName = person.LastName,
            MobileNumber = person.MobileNumber,
            LandlineNumber = person.LandlineNumber,
            Email = person.Email, //Error
            DOB = person.DOB, //Error
            Active = person.Active //Error
        }.ToList()
 }
```

Comment: Thank you as this is a good option. But the i have already one class with name "RetriveOperatorAcYo" so I dont want to use a new class. and I need to follow this pattern. So..!!

Comment: Very well. So instead of `PersonDTO` you can just use the class that you have. But you have to realize that using either of these two, you cannot create a partial EF object. see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325797/the-entity-cannot-be-constructed-in-a-linq-to-entities-query).

Answer (score 0):

Having read all the discussion, and great suggestions, I think your answer is, **No**, there is not any solution how to map the data and return the particular mapped class with particular details only.  I think you will have to call Microsoft and persuade them to change how EF should accept partial objects.  This is the correct answer since you do not want to change existing code.

Comment: I found the guy from Microsoft who did the changes to EF for me. The guy's name is @Mark. Please contact for future references to him :) ;) :p