# Populate an Object from a Database using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am connected to a Database using `Entity Framework`. Now, I want to create a `List<Object>` of the data received using `Linq`

So, I have:

```
var listOfSettings = new List<AppSetting>();

var query = from appSetting in AppSettings
            where appSetting.AppConfigID == appConfigId
            select new AppSetting()
            {
                AppSettingID = Int16.Parse(appSetting.AppSettingID),
                ...

            };
```

How can I add that `AppSetting Object` to the `List` of Settings?

Comment: What have you tried to do so far, and what problems have you had with your current attempts to solve this problem or to find an existing solution?

Comment: No. I am trying to `listOfSettings.add(new AppSetting(){.......});` directly from the database

Comment: If you want to add `query` to `listOfSettings`, try `listOfSettings.AddRange(query)`

Comment: @paqogomez or, if he's just creating a new list, he could use `query.ToList()` instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return list using select new in LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370028/return-list-using-select-new-in-linq)

Answer (score 2):

```
List<AppSetting> listOfSettings = (from appSetting in AppSettings
                                  where appSetting.AppConfigID == appConfigId
                                  select new AppSetting()
                                  {
                                      AppSettingID = Int16.Parse(appSetting.Name),
                                      ...

                                  }).ToList();
```

Comment: Put the query between (). Something like (from appSetting...............).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

At the end, I had to do it like this:

```
var query = (AppSettings.Select(appSetting => new
            {
                AppSettingID = appSetting.AppSettingID,
                ...
            }).Where(appSetting => appSetting.AppConfigID == appConfigId)).ToList();

            listOfAppSettings.AddRange(query.Select(setting => new AppSetting()
            {
                AppSettingID = setting.AppSettingID, 
                ...
            }));
```