# How to write linq query (for different tables) that returns list

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq

**What I need**

The logged in user needs a list of all bugs that are linked to the projects the user is linked to/enrolled in.

**What I try**

I work in three layer (presentation - BLL - DALL) from the presentation layer I can send the pk_user_id. I try to write a Linq query that returns me a list of all the bugs. And I am lost on how to return that list.

I am quite new to Linq queries so I guess that's my problem. (I know I need to return my list at the end but I would be happy if I got to that point.

**All information I have**

I have a database with nine tables but only four that represent my problem 
[Bugs], [Users], [UsersOnProjects], [Projects].

**My relations**

```
[Users].pk_users_id         ->  [UsersOnsProjects].fk_users   
[Users].pk_users_id         ->  [Bugs].fk_creatorOfTheBug
[Users].pk_users_id         ->  [Bugs].fk_ResponsibleOfTheBug

[Projects].pk_projects_id   ->  [UsersOnProjects].fk_projects
[Projects].pk_projects_id   ->  [Bugs].fk_project
```

**Additional information**

I "think" I can't do anything with the relations of the table [Users] with [Bugs] because it is not the responsible or the creator that I need. It is the User that is logged in that needs to see every Bug that is linked to a project where he is enrolled in.

A user is linked to a project with the table [UsersOnPojects].
A bug is linked to a project.

**My code - 1 (her I get an error that I cannot convert the query to a list) **

```
  public List<Bug> getAllOnProject(int p_user)
        { 

            var query4 = from t in dc.Bugs
                         join s in dc.Projects
                         on t.fk_project equals s.pk_project_id
                         join u in dc.Users
                         on s.pk_project_id equals u.fk_project
                         join v in dc.Users
                         on u.fk_user equals v.pk_User_id
                         where v.pk_User_id == p_user
                         select new
                         {
                             t.fk_bugstatus,
                             t.fk_creator,
                             t.pk_bug_id,
                             t.title,
                             t.description,
                             t.date,
                             t.fk_priority,
                             t.fk_project,
                             t.fk_responsible,
                             t.openclosed
                         };
    }
```

My code try nr 2 (Here I have a list with all "correct" rows from [UsersOnProjects] but I don't know what to do next)

```
 public List<Bug> getAllOnProject(int p_user)
        {
            var query1 = from t in dc.UsersOnProjects
                         where t.fk_user == p_user
                         select t;

            List<UsersOnProject> x = query1.ToList();

            foreach (var c in x)
            { 

            }
      }
```

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return list using select new in LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370028/return-list-using-select-new-in-linq)

Comment: Add ToList() at the end of your linq query.

Comment: How is that even compiling? `getAllOnProject` doesn't return a value...

Comment: Is `UsersOnProjects` part of the class model, or have you got a pure many-to-many association between User and Project? (I.e. properties `User.Projects` and `Project.Users`).

Answer (score 2):

I think this might get your first attempt working - you just need to initialize your Bug entity so a `List<Bug>` can be created:

```
public static List<Bug> getAllOnProject(int p_user)
{
    var query4 = from t in dc.Bugs
                 join s in dc.Projects on t.fk_project equals s.pk_project_id
                 join u in dc.Users on s.pk_project_id equals u.fk_project
                 join v in dc.Users on u.fk_user equals v.pk_User_id
                 where v.pk_User_id == p_user
                 select new Bug
                 {
                     fk_bugstatus = t.fk_bugstatus,
                     fk_creator = t.fk_creator,
                     pk_bug_id = t.pk_bug_id,
                     title = t.title,
                     description = t.description,
                     date = t.date,
                     fk_priority = t.fk_priority,
                     fk_project = t.fk_project,
                     fk_responsible = t.fk_responsible,
                     openclosed = t.openclosed
                 };

    return query4.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume the existence of some navigation properties:

```
return (from p in dc.Projects
        where p.Users.Any(u => u.fk_users == pk_user_id)
        from b in p.Bugs
        select b).ToList();
```

General advice in composing LINQ queries is: use navigation properties in stead of these cluttered verbose joins. EF will generate all required SQL joins while you can use a much more succinct syntax.