# How to get how many rows that has a column with the same record

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, linq

Example table:

```
Name          Work        City

Bob           Work1       City2
Frank         Work2       City1
Will          Work3       City1
Lisa          Work4       City3
Alex          Work5       City2
```

How do I with entity framework find out how many names lives in a city?

So the output I get is "2,2,1" (2 City2, 2 city1, 1 city3)

Comment: Post the code you tried, table names, database names...

Comment: I'd do this in two stages. First, get a list of unique city names. Second, count how many rows have that city name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL to Entity Framework Count Group-By](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564311/sql-to-entity-framework-count-group-by)

Comment: `context.TableName.GroupBy(x => x.City).Select(x => new { name = x.Key, count = x.Count() });`

Comment: @RobinBennett I was thinking that that is what i need to do but i can't figure out how. Could you please explain how to me?

Answer (score 0):

If all are in the same table then the comment given by @CodingYoshi is the correct.

But if All are different table then its required for us to understand the Table structure.

You can do it multiple ways.

1. Join and Group by the table based on conditions.
2. Get each record and count up using for loop (not recommended)

Comment: It's all in the same table. When i try CodingYoshi's method i get `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: string Name, int count>>'`

Comment: `Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<<anonymous type: string User, int count>>' to 'int' DynamicBetting C:\Annevo\DynamicBetting\DynamicBetting\DynamicBetting\DynamicBetting\Pages\Betting\PlaceBet.cshtml.cs 65 Active`

Comment: I think you are converting the list into integer. can you please post what have you done?

Comment: Yeah that is wrong, i just can't figure out what datatype to use. `public int ScoreCount { get; set; }` 

`var scoreCount = _context.Bet.Where(i => i.MatchId == id).GroupBy(x => x.ScoreBetted).Select(a => new { User = a.Key, count = a.Count() });
            ScoreCount = scoreCount;`

Comment: _context.Bet.Where(i => i.MatchId == id).GroupBy(x => x.ScoreBetted).Select(a => new { User = a.Key, count = a.Count() }) will return the IEnumerable of anonymous type. You can Create the list of dictionary. or you can assign into your custom model. as answered into "https://stackoverflow.com/a/6370057/10309661"

Comment: @user10384441 My answer will return a `List<a>` where `a` is an anonymous type with two properties: `name` and `count`. You cannot assign that to an integer. It makes no sense.

Comment: Yeah i know that, it was just a left over from old testing. So is it `IList<name, count>` or how should that property look like?

Comment: Its Not `IList<name, count>` its will be the `List<a>` where `a` is anonymous type, you can access you can assign the value of the query shared into some `var` variable, Or you can create your custom model with property name and count, and access that `var` or custom model variable for fulfill your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that the data is as noted in your question you can do as follows

```
set.GroupBy(x => x.City)
   .Select(x => new { NamesCount = x.Distinct().Count(), City = x.Key })
```

if you are using linq-to-sql, you'll need to add a `ToList` before `Select` like this

```
set.GroupBy(x => x.City)
   .ToList()
   .Select(x => new { NamesCount = x.Distinct().Count(), City = x.Key })
```

Comment: I assume you should not take into account duplicates: `NamesCount = x.Select(x => x.Name).Distinct().Count()`