# Entity Framework + LINQ Expression outer join error

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, linq, left-join

i want to create a left outer join for a linq expression that query data from database via entity framework. this is the linq expression. basically what I am trying to do is search  problem_vehicle_id from problemVehiclesTicket in Problems table to see if it exists, if it doesn't exists, i want to return a problem object that is null/empty. Basically I believe it is left outer join.

```
   var ticketsDetails = (from tickets in DbContext.tickets
                                       join problemVehiclesTicket in DbContext.problem_vehicle on tickets.tickets_id equals problemVehiclesTicket.tickets_id
                                       join problems in DbContext.problem on problemVehiclesTicket.problem_vehicle_id equals problem.problem_vehicle_id into problemGroup
                                       from problems in problemGroup.DefaultIfEmpty(new problem { })
                                       where (tickets.tickets_id == ticketsId)
                                       select new TicketsDetails
                                       {
                                           Ticket = tickets,
                                           ProblemVehicle = problemVehiclesTicket,
                                           Problems= problem,
                                       }).ToList();
```

Problem is a class that mirrors that of the Problem table in database

```
`Problem`
id (int), description (string), type (short)
```

The error i got is "The entity or complex type 'SPOTS_Repository.speeding_offence' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query." The source is from Entity Framework.

any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The easiest (and standard) way is to remove `new problem { }` from `DefaultIfEmpty` call, i.e. use the parameterless overload `DefaultIfEmpty()` which will give you a `null` problem  instance in case there is no match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `problem` in your case is a mapped entity. Therefore, you cannot project onto it. You can use an anonymous type or another non-mapped class (DTO).

Because in your `DefaultIfEmpty` method you are constructing a new `problem`, which is a mapped entity, this not allowed.

**Fix**

You do not need to pass anything to `DefaultIfEmpty` method. Actually in your case, you are not even allowed because the only thing you can pass is `problem` and that is mapped. Therefore, use `.DefaultIfEmpty()` without creating a new `problem`.

**More Belabor**

Here is an example, which will clarify the usage of `DefaultIfEmpty`:

**Option 1: DefaultIfEmpty() with No Parameter**

```
var list1 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 6, 4 };
var list2 = new List<int> { 4, 1, 2 };
var selection =
    from l1 in list1
    join l2 in list2 on l1 equals l2 into joined
    from j in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select j;
```

Output: `1, 2, 0, 0, 4`
Why? Because 3 and 6 are not found and `DefaultIfEmpty` for an `integer` returns a 0.

**Option 2: DefaultIfEmpty() with Parameter**

In some cases we may want to indicate that if the item is not found in the join, what to return instead. We can do that by sending a single parameter to `DefaultIfEmpty` method like this:

```
var list1 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 6, 4 };
var list2 = new List<int> { 4, 1, 2 };
var selection =
    from l1 in list1
    join l2 in list2 on l1 equals l2 into joined
    from j in joined.DefaultIfEmpty(99) //<-- see this
    select j;
```

Output: `1, 2, 99, 99, 4` Why? Because 3 and 6 are not found and we instructed `DefaultIfEmpty` to return a `99` in that case.

Please note that `DefaultIfEmpty` is a generic method. In my case it required an `int` because I am joining to the second list which is a `List` of `int`(s). In your case it is `problem`(s) but that is mapped. Therefore, you cannot construct it in your query.

Here is another example:

```
var depts = new List<Department>
{
    new Department { Name = "Accounting" },
    new Department { Name = "IT" },
    new Department { Name = "Marketing" }
};
var persons = new List<Person>
{
    new Person { DeptName = "Accounting", Name = "Bob" }
};

var selection2 =
    from d in depts
    join p in persons on d.Name equals p.DeptName into joined2
    // See here DefaultIfEmpty can be passed a Person
    from j2 in joined2.DefaultIfEmpty(new Person { DeptName = "Unknown", Name = "Alien" })
    select j2;

foreach(var thisJ in selection2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Dept: {0}, Name: {1}", thisJ.DeptName, thisJ.Name);
}
```

Output:

```
Dept: Accounting, Name: Bob
Dept: Unknown, Name: Alien
Dept: Unknown, Name: Alien
```

[<== Fiddle Me ==>](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xAomfJ)

Comment: sorry, i dont get what you are trying to do here. are you trying to instantiate an anonymous type?

Comment: Yes instead of instantiating your mapped entity class, use an anonymous type. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25304665/linq-with-defaultifempty-with-select-new) for more details.

Comment: does that mean if my Problem has 10 variables, i need to do for 10 of them?

Answer (score 0):

```
Public class problem()
{
public int id;
public string description;
public short type;
}

.DefaultIfEmpty(
    new problem()
    {
        Id = ticketsId,
        Description = string.empty,
    });
```

create class and make use of that in linq query
Hope it helps you.

Comment: that's a great freaking explaination. thank you so much