# RSS feed in asp.net mvc giving exception

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am having a problem while using RSS feed in MVC5.
I have used the whole code from this post
[LINK](http://damieng.com/blog/2010/04/26/creating-rss-feeds-in-asp-net-mvc#comments)

But when I run the project I got this Error. Any Help ?

[image]

Comment: You should copy the text of the exception and include it in your post, not a screenshot. I'd like to try to help but I can't read the text on the screenshot.

Comment: simply delete the question

Answer (score 0):

Really you should include stacktrace or smth more helpful than screenshot. While my eyes are full of blood tears after staring at this screenshot, I have an idea that you probably have a problem in **Data Layer** . Something is wrong in the code that retrieves data from DB using Entity Framework. Pay more attention to **Additional Information** in exception. I think this is [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571084/only-parameterless-constructors-and-initializers-are-supported-in-linq-to-entiti)