# In constructors and initializers, only property or field parameter bindings are supported in LINQ to Entities. ViewModel in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

```
public List<TicketViewModel> GetTickets()
{
    DBEntities db = new DBEntities();

    List<TicketViewModel> tickets =
        (from ticket in db.Tickets
            join user in db.AspNetUsers on ticket.user_id equals user.Id
            join cat in db.TicketCategories on ticket.sub_category_id equals cat.id
            where ticket.is_active == true
            select new TicketViewModel
            {
                username = user.UserName,
                id = ticket.id,
                subject = ticket.subject,
                message = ticket.message,
                user_id = ticket.user_id,
                priority = (int)ticket.priority,
                date_created = ticket.date_created,
                date_modified = ticket.date_modified,
                assigned_to = ticket.assigned_to,
                is_active = ticket.is_active,
                sub_category_id = (int)ticket.sub_category_id,
                attatchments = ticket.attatchments,
                ticket_type = cat.name,
            }).ToList();

    return tickets;
}
```

I am receiving the above error whilst trying to obtain a list of tickets. The `TicketViewModel` is an 'extended' ViewModel of the `TicketModel` which contains the additional username and category parameters not stored in the initial `TicketModel` class.

I have read [Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571084/only-parameterless-constructors-and-initializers-are-supported-in-linq-to-entiti) but this doesn't seem to cover the use of ViewModels in Linq

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, can anyone help?

Edit: Added TicketViewModel class below.

```
public class TicketViewModel
{

    private DBEntities db = new DBEntities();

    [DisplayName("Ticket ID")]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("User ID")]
    public string user_id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Username")]
    public string username { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Subject")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "required")]
    public string subject { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Message")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "required")]
    public string message { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Active")]
    public bool is_active { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Date Created")]
    public DateTime date_created { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Date Modified")]
    public DateTime date_modified { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Category")]
    public int sub_category_id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Assigned To")]
    public string assigned_to { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Attatchments")]
    public string attatchments { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Priority")]
    public int priority { get; set; }

    public List<Attatchment> _attatchments = new List<Attatchment>();

    public string ticket_type = "";

    public int comments = 0;

    public List<SelectListItem> PrioritySelection = new List<SelectListItem>(){
        new SelectListItem(){Value = "1", Text = "Low"},
        new SelectListItem(){Value = "2", Text = "Medium"},
        new SelectListItem(){Value = "3", Text = "High"}
    };
}
```

Comment: Can you represent the database table structure too..

Comment: Should there be a comma after cat.name?

Comment: have you tried the second solution from the SO link you provided?

Comment: Post the definition for `TicketViewModel` (and any inherited classes).

Comment: Is there any additional code in the constructor or property setters of `TicketViewModel/TicketModel`?

Comment: Updated post to include TicketViewModel. I have tried using the below code successfully with a foreach loop to set username and category names but its longwinded and ideally I would like to do it as per above code.
`List<Ticket> tickets = db.Tickets.Where(t => t.is_active == false).ToList();
List<TicketViewModel> _tickets = new List<TicketViewModel>();`