# Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities. GeoCoordinate(latitude, longitude);

Tags: c#, linq

I have this situation: I need to find nearby location using lat and long. 
Using this:

```
var coord = new GeoCoordinate(latitude, longitude);
                var nearest = context.ParkingSpaces.Select(x => new GeoCoordinate(x.Latitude.Value, x.Longitude.Value))
                                         .OrderBy(x => x.GetDistanceTo(coord)).First();
```

But I am getting following error:

Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities

Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571084/only-parameterless-constructors-and-initializers-are-supported-in-linq-to-entiti)

Comment: Yes. I visited that page. But couldn't find proper solution for GeoCoordinate

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite to something like this:

```
var coord = new GeoCoordinate(latitude, longitude);
var nearest = context.ParkingSpaces
     .Select(x => new { Latitude = x.Latitude.Value, Longitude = x.Longitude.Value })
     .ToList()
     .Select(x => new GeoCoordinate(Latitude, Longitude))
     .OrderBy(x => x.GetDistanceTo(coord))
     .First();
```