# Code First Entity Framework, select ViewModel - constructor with parameter

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, constructor

I create class Employee:

```
public class Employees : BaseModel
{
    [Key]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
   // [ohter parameter]
    public int? DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Departments Departments { get; set; }
    public int? OccupationId { get; set; }
    public virtual Occupations Occupations { get; set; }
}
```

I want to create a view model.

```
public class Employee_ViewModel 
{
    public Employee_ViewModel(Employees item)
    {
        this.EmployeeId = item.EmployeeId;
        //[other parameter]
        this.DepartmentId = item.DepartmentId;
        this.OccupationId = item.OccupationId;
    }

    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    //[other parameter]
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public string OccupationName { get; set; }
}
```

my method which returns Employee_ViewModel look like:

```
 List<Employee_ViewModel> item = contex.Employees.Where(w => w.IsActive == true && w.IsVisible == true)
                                     .Include(i => i.Departments)
                                     .Include(i => i.Occupations)
                                     .Select(s => new Employee_ViewModel(s)
                                     {
                                         OccupationName = s.Occupations.Name,
                                         DepartmentName = s.Departments.Name
                                     })
                                     .ToList();
```

Finally I get error:

> Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.

Solution form the this post:

[Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571084/only-parameterless-constructors-and-initializers-are-supported-in-linq-to-entiti)

is working but why my constructor doesn't work?

Comment: Isn't it obvious from the exception message (the word **parameterless**). Also this has been asked many times http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Only+parameterless+constructors+and+initializers+are+supported+in+LINQ+to+Entities.

Comment: I know but I want to rewrite the parameters easier.

Answer (score 2):

As other tools, Entity Framework creates proxies of your models on run-time, and these are emitted as derived classes of your models. Clearly, you can't expect a proxy generator to use a constructor with parameters to instantiate your model.

In summary: keep it simple, use the tool the way it's meant to be used: your entities should contain at least their parameterless constructor.

**Consider using [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to keep things simple**:

```
// If you go for the AutoMapper approach, you need no constructor 
// with parameters or factory method anymore!
List<Employee_ViewModel> item = contex.Employees.Where(w => w.IsActive == true && w.IsVisible == true)
                                     .Include(i => i.Departments)
                                     .Include(i => i.Occupations)
                                     .ProjectTo<EmployeeViewModel>()
                                     .ToList();
```

See AutoMapper's docs to [queryable extensions](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions) to learn more about how to combine it with Entity Framework.

Comment: I used solution with functions From, but return error: _LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'MS.ViewModel.Employee_ViewModel From(MS.Models.Employees)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression._ 
What about performance, better use AutoMapper?

Comment: Adding ToList() before Select solving a problem. But is correct solution?

Comment: @18666 My first attemp was wrong. You're right, expression trees should be translatable to SQL and a custom factory isn't possible to be translated into SQL. **See my updated answer on which I've thrown away the wrong part, and I've edited the AutoMapper approach**.

Comment: @18666 As of your attemp of calling ToList and later Select, it's not a good idea, because usually you don't want to get your entire table in memory to do filters, projections and so on. Probably you want them to happen in the database.